# Error: Use of undeclared identifier 'SSL_get_secure_renegotiation_support'; did you mean 'GRPC_SHADOW_SSL_get_secure_renegotiation_support'?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I got an error when building an app after install pod 'Firebase/Firestore'.

[image]

I'm using Xcode 11.2.1, cocoapods version 1.8.4, and macOS 10.15.1

This is content in Podfile

[image]

Comment: Be sure to open your app with the .xcworkspace file, not the .xcodeproj file. You may want to deintegrate your pod and fresh install using the --verbose switch to catch any errors. Also check you apps deployment target iOS Version.

Comment: Running into the same issue, here's how I resolved it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64364518/2162226

Answer (score 1):

Try `pod deintegrate` and `pod update`. If that doesn't work, share the contents of the `Podfile.lock` in the question.

Comment: That doesn't work :( And I dont know how to share the contents of the Podfile.lock here, it has too many characters, so I sent it to Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kptmTv3lSGrDtwtp8rLGw8FzJtylC9AN